# How do I save as .osm in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

The directions in http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/osm/openstreetmap.html#saving-osm-data seem to have been written before the OSM plugin was merged into QGIS proper. I can locate no OSM plugin or toolbar, and the vector menu only has options for opening a .osm file in QGIS.

Comment: Is there any possibility ( in QGIS 2.4) to edit some data (shape file for example) in QGIS and then upload to OpenStreetMap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the update of the OSM plugin, all editing and uploading functions of the plugin are removed.

The standard OSM editors have much better capabilities of editing and internal checking than QGIS can provide.

The manual page you mentioned has been forgotten to be dropped. Maybe underdark can do something about that.

Comment: By the way, there are other programs such as gpsbabel that can convert shapefiles to osm. I was just wondering if QGIS could still do it.

Comment: I doubt that gpsbabel will create userids and version numbers correctly. Keep in mind that your new data will have to fit into existing data, and roads should be connected to existing roads.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays the best way to transform GIS data to OSM is to open it (GML, SHP, ...) in JOSM with OpenData Plugin (1) activated and, if you want, you can save it to *.osm format.

(1) https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Plugins/OpenData

Comment: JOSM is not an option, it extremely sluggish, slow and cant handle larger datasets. I tried it. I really think that QGIS should have the option to export layers / Geopackage to OSM.