# Download Black Sea contours (OpenStreetMap)

Tags: qgis

I need to download the contours of the Black Sea. Using the program QGIS (plugin QuickOSM), I was able to download the contours of the Sea of Azov. But I could not do this for the Black Sea. Need a script that will give me the Black Sea multipolygon. I get the Sea of Azov using a script (below) no problems.
https://overpass-turbo.eu/

```
<osm-script output="xml" timeout="75">
    <id-query {{geocodeArea:Sea Of Azov}} into="area_0"/>
    <union>
        <query type="relation">
            <has-kv k="place" v="sea"/>
            <area-query from="area_0"/>
        </query>
    </union>
    <union>
        <item/>
        <recurse type="down"/>
    </union>
    <print mode="body"/>
</osm-script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by contour? Coastlines of Black Sea or elevation contour lines?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the bathymetric DEM from here: https://download.gebco.net/

Here is what it looks like in QGIS once you download the tiff.[image]

You can use Raster -> Extraction -> Contour to create the contour lines spaced however you like.

Here is what they look like with 50ft intervals:[image]

And with 250 ft intervals:[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I need an OSM vector. I can’t pull out the multipolygon from https://overpass-turbo.eu/

Comment: You can convert the vector to OSM format using the JOSM: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107061/how-do-i-save-as-osm-in-qgis

Comment: Completed the question

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear that.